# Crackling Sound when playing two distinct Sounds Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, alsa, 15.10, matlab

everytime I play two different sounds (a youtubevideo and a video from another site, or two distinct audioplayer sources in matlab) the second sound is all crackling and fizzy. How can I resolve this?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 64bit and I have a ASRock z77 Extreme 4 Motherboard.

Edit:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:963:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:963:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm.c:7905:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7905:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

When I start matlab from the terminal and the sound problmes occur - this is what comes in the terminal.

Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I 'fixed' the problem by turning down the (master) volume at the soundcontrol - I think my onbaord soundcard had problems with an amplitude this high.

Comment: Every audio device has a limit to how high of an amplitude it can handle. When you reach this limit, it's called [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(signal_processing)). When it's really bad, it can actually damage hardware.